# Covering the Camera the "void Update" is stop working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I just want to know if there is a possibility to check if the user "Covering the Camera with their hand" because I tried it to myself, Once I cover the AR Camera the void Update is suddenly stop working but the object on AR World is still there. I want to check if the user Covering the Camera then SetActive(false) all the GameObject on AR world.

Comment: Could you specify what `"Covering the Camera"` is? like cover it with hand? and no in that case it will not stop `Update()`. It will not able to track the plane and anchor points to properly update the objects accordingly.

Comment: @DigvijaysinhGohil Sorry for not specifying the "Covering the Camera". How can I check if user is covering the Camera with his/her hand because I want to create A trigger function to "SetActive(false)" all the GameObject when the user covering the Camera with their hand.